# What is the correct way to call a class instance inside another class's method?

Tags: ruby, oop

I am trying to make a simple library app, and I am trying to implement a method where a person gets to borrow a book. I have so far 2 classes one for the said person and the other is for books/documents. 
The person(adherant) class (which includes a test case):

```
require_relative 'document'
class Adherant
  attr_reader :id,:nom, :prenom,:emprunt
  def initialize(id,nom, prenom)
    @id=id
    @nom  = nom
    @prenom = prenom
  end

  def emprunt
    @emprunt =0
  end

  def to_s
      "Adherant N°: #{@id}- #{@nom} #{@prenom}"
  end

  def emprunter(other)
    if other.empruntable==true && @emprunt <5
      puts "Vous avez emprunter: #{other.titre}"
      other.empruntable==false #there was a trailing `=` causing problems too
      @emprunt+=1
    else
      puts "#{@emprunt.inspect} #{other.empruntable.inspect}"
      puts "#{other.titre} est deja emprunter!"
    end
  end
end

livr= Document.new("Harry Potter And The Goblet Of Fire",12345,"J.K Rowling","livre")
test = Adherant.new(123,"Doe","John")
test.emprunter(livr)
```

The document class:

```
class Document
  attr_accessor :titre, :isbn, :auteur,:type,:empruntable

  def initialize(titre, isbn, auteur,type)
    @titre  = titre
    @isbn = isbn
    @auteur = auteur
    @type = type
  end
  def self.empruntable
    @empruntable = true
  end
  def to_s
    "#{@type.capitalize}:#{@titre.capitalize}- #{@auteur.capitalize} #ISBN: #{@isbn.to_s.capitalize}"
  end
end
```

The output:

```
nil nil
Harry Potter And The Goblet Of Fire est deja emprunter!
```

I don't understand why the adherant `@emprunt` and document `@empruntable` have nil values whilst I made sure to give them a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tests and looking the problem up, I found a way to make it work.
I used flexible initialization, by giving the `@emprunt` and `@empruntable` attributes a default value in the `initialize` method.
The person(adherant) class (which includes a test case):

```
require_relative 'document'
class Adherant
  attr_reader :id,:nom, :prenom,:emprunt
  def initialize(id,nom, prenom, emprunt=0)
    @id=id
    @nom  = nom
    @prenom = prenom
    @emprunt = emprunt
  end

  #def emprunt
   # @emprunt =0
  #end

  def to_s
      "Adherant N°: #{@id}- #{@nom} #{@prenom}"
  end

  def emprunter(other)
    if other.empruntable==true && @emprunt <5
      puts "Vous avez emprunter: #{other.titre}"
      other.empruntable=false
      @emprunt+=1
    else
      puts "#{other.titre} est deja emprunter!"
    end
  end
end

livr= Document.new("Harry Potter And The Goblet Of Fire",12345,"J.K Rowling","livre")
puts livr.empruntable
test = Adherant.new(123,"Doe","John")
test.emprunter(livr)
puts livr.empruntable
```

The document class:

```
class Document
  attr_accessor :titre, :isbn, :auteur,:type,:empruntable

  def initialize(titre, isbn, auteur,type,empruntable=true)
    @titre  = titre
    @isbn = isbn
    @auteur = auteur
    @type = type
    @empruntable = empruntable
  end
  #def self.empruntable 
   # @empruntable = true
  #end
  def to_s
    "#{@type.capitalize}:#{@titre.capitalize}- #{@auteur.capitalize} #ISBN: #{@isbn.to_s.capitalize}"
  end
end
```

The new output:

```
true
Vous avez emprunter: Harry Potter And The Goblet Of Fire!
false
```

Comment: That's because you're not setting that value

Comment: Your test is incomplete. Should call all methods that you need to call and assert expected values.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev my bad I didn't include the actual test in the question (I changed it now), but that still doesn't change the livr.empruntable value.

Comment: because see my first comment (`==` is not assignment)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I just saw that additional `=` sign thanks ^^.

Comment: For the sanity of yourself and others you should use keyword arguments instead for that initializer `initialize(titre:, isbn:, auteur:, type:)`. Keyword arguments should always be used when there are multiple arguments without an obvious order. https://thoughtbot.com/upcase/videos/ruby-keyword-arguments

Comment: @max I was just starting out and didn't know much about those, while working on my current project I learned how to do so, thanks for the advice0